# Understanding how spark's task distribution works across cores

Tags: apache-spark

I came across a description about how tasks are distributed across executors in Spark framework. The excerpt from the book is as below :

"Each stage is comprised of Spark tasks (a unit of execution), which are then federated across each Spark executor; each task maps to a single core and works on a single partition of data (Figure 2-5). As such, an executor with 16 cores can have 16 or more tasks working on 16 or more partitions in parallel, making the execution of Spark’s tasks exceedingly parallel!

Damji, Jules S.; Wenig, Brooke; Das, Tathagata; Lee, Denny. Learning Spark (p. 59). O'Reilly Media."

If there are 16 cores, then Spark should technically schedule 16 tasks in parallel. Does the author mean that more than 1 task is scheduled on a core so that if one task is busy in I/O operation, other task can get hold of the core and starts its execution (time slicing in multi-tasking Or Hyperthreading)? If not, please explain how an executor with 16 cores can have 16 or more tasks working in parallel at any point in time.

Also, I believe 1:1 mapping is implied in above excerpt, between core/spark-task and partition. Is this true or can we have more than 16 partitions on an executor with 16 cores, but the task can only work with one partition AND when the computation by this task requires data from another partition, shuffle happens and required data is brought into the partition that this task is working on (i.e. task still works with one partition, but content of the partition changes via shuffle)?

I haven't looked up much around this issue elsewhere, however, stumbled upon [Spark: understanding partitioning - cores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46992060/spark-understanding-partitioning-cores) and [How is task distributed in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37737110/how-is-task-distributed-in-spark) to get new understandings about related concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author means that if you have 17 tasks, 16 tasks will be run in parallel. When one of the tasks is finished, the corresponding core will be assigned to do the 17th task, and you will have 16 tasks running in parallel again.